# Trouble using xlsxwriter in Python

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to automate the input of data in a spreadsheet using Python but I'm having a couple of issues:

- only being able to write 1 in excel
- not saving properly
- and probably using the wrong library

```
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('se.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
valores =[]
entra = 0
while entra != 2:
    Val = input("Favor informar a largura, o comprimento e a espessura o preco do material e tempo de corte em segundo separados por espaços: ") ##please enter the values of width length the thickness the material price per kilo and the cut time
    lst = Val.split()
    print(lst)
    L = int(lst[0])
    C = int(lst[1])
    E = int(lst[2])
    V = (L * C * E * 8) / 1000000
    P = int(lst[3])
    T = int(lst[4])
    Pt = (T * P) / 36
    lst.append(Pt)
    lst.append(V)
    entra = int(input("Digite 2 para fechar ou 1 para adicionar mais elementos: "))
    valores.append[lst]

    lst.clear()
    print(valores)
for row_num, row_data in enumerate(valores):
    for col_num, col_data in enumerate(row_data):
        worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, col_data)


# Salva o arquivo somente quando o loop terminar
workbook.close()
```

I am trying to enter data continually but I keep only writing one line and it writes over it.

Comment: Provided you are happy to create the workbook from scratch each time then Xlsxwriter is fine. But in case you are not aware, Xlsxwriter cannot read existing Excel files so attempting to update the file once created using this code will result in the existing file being overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

First off, there is a slight syntax error in `valores.append[lst]`, which should be `valores.append(lst)`, as `valores.append()` is a function call.

The reason your main problem occurred however, was the `lst.clear()` function. The `lst.clear()` function clears the list, but also the content of the identifier (variable) referring to that list, which you created with `valores.append(lst)`. Basically `lst` is linked to `valores`.

This means, that with `lst.clear()` you don't just clear `lst` of it's content, but also the `lst` which is inside `valores[0]`.

To avoid this, you need to re-define the `lst` identifier so that it is empty, which you do with `lst = []`.

Long story short,
you should use `lst = []` instead of `lst.clear()`

I hope this helped

Comment: `lst = []` is useless since `lst = Val.split()` does the job.

Answer (score 1):

It would be necessary at least :

- remove lst.clear()
- change valores.append[lst] to valores.append(lst)